# Have some doubts in the operation [Bitwise Manipulation]

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// converting from decimal to binary

int main()
{
    int n, bit, ans = 0, i = 0;
    cout << "enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        bit = n & 1;
        ans = round(bit * pow(10, i)) + ans; /* we used 'round' bcoz pow(10, 2) give 99.99999
                                                it differs from compiler to compiler  */
        n = n >> 1;
        i++;
    }

    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand that in **while(n>0)**, **n** will be stored as binary form or decimal form.
That is if **n=5**, so whether while loop check for **(5>0)** or **(101>0)**.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

I am new to this platform, please don't delete my question. My earlier questions are also gets deleted due enough dislikes. I am here to learn and am still learning.

Comment: `5` and `0b101` are the same thing.

Comment: Bitwise manimulation doesn't "change" a 5 to 101, 101 _is_ how 5 is stored.

Comment: "Decimal" and "Binary" are *text* representations of a value. `n` is an `int`, not text, so it holds the value 5.  If I have 5 apples on a desk, then there is no "decimal" or "binary" involved. THere's just 5 apples. Same with `int`.

Comment: `pow(10, i)` is wrong you should not mix floating point calculations with integer ones (rounding errors). Just have an integer that you multiply by integer 10 for each time you loop

Comment: Can anyone please explain how while loop is working here?

Comment: The loop will run while `n > 0`, period. Shifting `n >> 1` divides by two *(remainder tossed)*: `n = 0b101 >> 1 == 0b10`, which is `4`. That's it. Repeat while `n > 0`.

Comment: [introduction-to-loops-and-while-statements](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-loops-and-while-statements/), or for reference [while](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) from cppreference.com (the goto site to lookup things). Also stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: @PepijnKramer then what should I use ?

Comment: `n>>1` shifts all bits of n one to the right, and adds 0 bit to the left. At one moment all bits are 0, and n is zero (which is false) and the loop ends.

Comment: outside loop, int pow = 1;  inside loop pow *=10; which is full integer arithmetic. Or do you mean instead of `using namespace std` ? Then type std:: where needed (in bigger projects this will avoid nameclashes)

Comment: `0` is `0` whether it is binary or decimal. Fun fact: `0` is an octal literal.

Comment: @VaibhavKumar `we used 'round' bcoz pow(10, 2) give 99.99999 it differs from compiler to compiler` -- Do not use `pow` or `round` at all in a program like this.  Do not use floating point functions in programs that are integer-based.  There is no guarantee that your "fix" will work for every test case and every compiler.  Instead, have a simple `int` table of powers of 10, and index into it.

Comment: @DaveNewton what is 'b' here ?
n = 0b101 >> 1 == 0b10

Comment: @VaibhavKumar `b` for binary

Comment: @DaveNewton I am basically asking what is '0b' here **-**
n = **0b**101 >> 1 == **0b**10

Comment: @VaibhavKumar `b` for binary? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Decimal" and "Binary" are text representations of a value. `n` is an `int`, not text, so it holds the value `5`. If I have 5 apples on a desk, then there is no "decimal" or "binary" involved. THere's just 5 apples. Same with `int`.

```
cin >> n;
while (n > 0)
```

This loop continues because `5 > 0`.

```
n = n >> 1;
```

This is just a fancy way of writing `n = n / 2`, so then `n` becomes `2`. Since `2 > 0`, the loop continues.  On the third run, `n` becomes `1`, and since `1 > 0`, the loop continues a third time. On the fourth run, `n` becomes `0`, and `0 == 0`, so the while loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

Both `n` and `ans` are integers that your computer stores in a binary format. If `n = 5` then `n` is both `5` and `0b0101`. Your loop converts one integer `n` into a second integer `ans` which only uses the digits 1 and 0 and looks like the integer `n` in binary.

It does this by converting each power of two in `n` into a power of ten and adding it into `ans`. The integer `5` will become the integer `101` (one hundred and one).

In the loop, when you use the bitwise operator `>>` you are manipulating the underlying binary representation of the number directly, in this case, shifting all of the bits in the integer to the right and feeding in zeros on the left to replace the bits that have moved.

So, if `n` is 5 then:

```
0b0101 >> 1  gives 0b0010, or 2
0b0101 >> 2  gives 0b0001, or 1
0b0101 >> 3  gives 0b0000, or 0
```

When you use the bitwise operator `&` (bitwise and) you are again operating directly on the binary representation. This time you are and-ing all of the bits in one number with the bit in another number. For example:

```
0b01100110 & 0b10101110 = 0b00100110
0b01100110 & 0b10011001 = 0b00000000
```

In your loop you are doing four things:

**1. `bit = n & 1`**

And-ing the integer `n` with one will mean that `bit` is equal to:

- 1 when there is a 1 in the 2^0 place (the least significant bit) and,
- 0 when there is not a 1 in the 2^0 place.

**2. `ans = round(bit * pow(10, i)) + ans`**

You take 10^i and multiply it by bit. So:

- `bit` is zero this is zero
- if `bit` is one this is some power of ten.

**3. `n = n >> 1`**

Shift one place to the right. The bit that was in the 2^1 place is now in the 2^0 place.

**4. `i++`**

Increment `i` which tracks both your current power of 2 and current power of ten.

Comment: 0b0101 >> 1  
what is 'b' here ?

Comment: The `0b` signifies that this is a binary literal. You could use `n = 5` or `n = 0b0101` and `n` would get the same value. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Answer (score 0):

@Mooing Duck has explained it incredibly well. I'd just add that you are being confused about the **Number System**

- Decimal numbers are called the base 10 numbers (digits: *0 - 9*, total: 10)
- Binary numbers are called the base 2 numbers(digits/bits: *0 - 1*, total: 2)
- 101 (*base* **10**) is very different from 101 (*base* **2**)
- When we use bitwise operators such as (<<, >>, &, ^, |) we manipulate the bits of the decimal (hence the name bitwise operators)
- So, when you are doing `5 >> 1` you are actually doing `101 (base 2) >> 1` which results in `010 (base 2)`
- When you keep shifting the bits to the right(equivalent to dividing by 2), at one point you'll be left with no **1s** and only **0s**. And what's 0 (base 2)? Its 0(base 10). Hence, the loop breaks.